# PCIe Bandwidth on ATI FirePro

Tags: opencl

I am trying to measure PCIe Bandwidth on ATI FirePro 8750. The amd app sample PCIeBandwidth  in the SDK measures the bandwith of transfers from:

1. Host to device, using clEnqueueReadBuffer().
2. Device to host, using clEnqueueWriteBuffer().

On my system (windows 7, Intel Core2Duo 32 bit) the output is coming like this:

```
Selected Platform Vendor : Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
Device 0 : ATI RV770
Host to device : 0.412435 GB/s
Device to host : 0.792844 GB/s
```

This particular card has 2 GB DRAM and max clock frequency is 750 Mhz

1- Why is bandwidth different in each direction?

2- Why is the Bandwdith so small?

Also I understand that this communication takes place through DMA, so the Bandwidth may not be affected by CPU.

Comment: What CPU are you using?  The CPU can often times bottleneck the PCIe transfer if it's bad enough.

Comment: the transfer is taking place through DMA, (the buffers are always pinned before this transfer), how does that matter whether CPU is bad or good

Comment: Your GPU is on a x16 lane.. right?

Comment: What is your system memory's speed? If under Windows Vista or greater, go into your command line and type "winsat mem". I mean, it should be more than that, but you never know..

Comment: system memory performance:   2011.77 MB/s

Comment: That is extremely low... have you tried the same code on a different system but with the same graphics card?

Answer (score 0):

This [paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/172730/20120625%20UCAA2012_Bittner_Ruf_Final.pdf) from Microsoft Research labs give some inkling of why there is asymmetric PCIe data transfer bandwidth between GPU - CPU.  The paper describes performance metrics for FPGA - GPU data transfer bandwidth  over PCIe. It also includes metrics from CPU - GPU data transfer bandwidth over PCIe.

To quote the relevant section

> 'it should also be noted that the GPU-CPU transfers themselves also
>   show some degree of asymmetric behavior. In the case of a GPU to CPU
>   transfer, where the GPU is initiating bus master writes, the GPU
>   reaches a maximum of
>   6.18 GByte/Sec. In the opposite direction from CPU to GPU, the GPU is initiating bus master reads and the resulting bandwidth falls to 5.61
>   GByte/Sec. In our observations it is typically the case that bus
>   master writes are more efficient than bus master reads for any PCIe
>   implementation due to protocol overhead and the relative complexity of
>   implementation. While a possible solution to this asymmetry would be
>   to handle the CPU to GPU direction by using CPU initiated bus master
>   writes, that hardware facility is not available in the PC architecture
>   in general. '

The answer to the second question on bandwidth could be due units of data transfer size.
See figs 2,3,4 and 5. I have also seen graphs like this at the 1st AMD Fusion Conference. The explanation is that the PCIe transfer of data has overheads due to the protocol and the device latency.  The overheads are more significant for small transfer sizes and become less significant for larger sizes.

**What levers do you have to control or improve performance?**

Getting the right combo of chip/motherboard and GPU is the H/W lever. Chips with the  max number of PCIe lanes are better. Using a higher spec PCIe protocol, PCIe 3.0 is better than PCIe 2.0. All components need to support the higher standards.

As a programmer controlling the data transfer size, is a very important lever.

Transfer sizes of 128K - 256K bytes get approx 50% of the max bandwidth. Transfers of 1M - 2M bytes get over 90% of max bandwidth.